# Cannot update template in angular 2 when data is changed

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a form to insert data to a table. When i delete data from table , the data is removed but the table row is not deleted. 
It appears that the data is two way binding so data is removed but the html structure remains same.

Component

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit { 

studentform = new FormGroup({
    id: new FormControl(),
    name: new FormControl(),
    address: new FormControl()
});

student: Student[]=[];
std: Student= new Student();
constructor(public homeService: HomeService){ }

OnInit(){
  this.getData();
}

getData(){
     this.student = this.homeService.GetData();
}

onEdit(id:number){      
    console.log("Edit:" + id);   
}

onDelete(id:number){
   this.homeService.delete(id); 
   this.getData();    
}

Save(model:Student){       
    this.homeService.SaveData(model);        
    this.studentform.reset(); 
    this.getData();

}

}
```

Service

```
@Injectable()
export class HomeService{

student:Student[]=[];

SaveData(model:Student){
  this.student.push(model);
}

GetData(){
 return this.student;
}

delete(id:number){
  for(var i=0;i<this.student.length;i++){
       if(this.student[i].id==id){
           delete this.student[i]
       }
   }  
}

}
```

Template

```
div class="col-md-6">

<h5> Lists </h5>

<table>
   <th>ID  </th>
   <th>Name  </th>
   <th>Address  </th>
   <th>Edit  </th>
   <th>Delete  </th>

    <tr *ngFor="let x of student">                  
       <td> {{ x.id }} </td>
       <td> {{ x.name }} </td>
       <td> {{ x.address }} </td>
       <td (click)="onEdit(x.id)"> Edit </td>
       <td (click)="onDelete(x.id)">  Delete </td>           
    </tr>

</table>
```

Help me update the html (template) when data changes.

This is the result after I click table : data is gone but row remains

[image]

Comment: @echonax, its not about data , its about view, data is updated view is not.
how do i remove the row, when the delete is clicked, will the view be rendered again? i dont think so, thats why there is empty row.
Please help me clearify

Comment: You see the error you are getting right? It tries to select `id` of something `undefined` in your html. Try the second solution in the link above.

Comment: @echonax , add data , click delete : no error, again add data click :delete generates error again,
Any way, even if i get no error, the empty row still exists, i want to remove that row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually deleting the object but it's reference remain in the primary array. Try this instead :

```
delete(id:number){
  for(var i=0;i<this.student.length;i++){
       if(this.student[i].id==id){
           this.student.splice(i, 1); //delete this.student[i]
           break;
       }
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`delete this.student[i]` is not the correct way to remove an element from an array in this situation. You need to use [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```
this.student.splice(i, 1);
```

Also you should do a truthy check when displaying object fields in the template. Otherwise you will get errors like that. Usually safe-navigation operator(`?`) will do the trick.

Example:

```
<td> {{ x?.id }} </td>
```